# How to format cell color based on another cell color

Tags: excel-formula

I have a worksheet where the cells in column A change fill color based on weekend by a CF. I would like the entire connected row to change to that color based on color of cell in column A.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without an example, but, maybe,you could change the range of CF to all the rows.

Comment: Thank you but that did not work. column A has dates that tune blue fill when date is weekend. This changes automatically on opening file. (using "=today() "function )

Comment: the CF i put on column A is:  =OR(WEEKDAY(A1)=1,WEEKDAY(A1)=7) but now i need to format the connecting row of data to same color as cell in A that turned blue from CF upon opening file.

Comment: i am new to using stackoverflow, how can i show you a screen shot?

Comment: Oavinegro, i uploaded a sample of what i need to do: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgOQ6PGbg2zCpAmRZ1hp_5dKpvn4

Comment: 1drv.ms/x/s!AgOQ6PGbg2zCpAmRZ1hp_5dKpvn4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found was creating, manually, a rule for each colunm. It worked. If you want to do this only for this sheet, it will be easy to do. To create the condition to the colunm B, select a cell on the column B, go to CF, new rule, and paste the formula. So, aply to $B$1:$B$26. Do the same with columns C, D...
See the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT6qL.png)

I edited the uploaded file too.